# Insertion sort issues?

Tags: c++, sorting

I'm just now trying out different sorting algorithms to find out how they work.

I'm looking at this one:

```
template< typename Iterator >
void insertion_sort( Iterator First, Iterator Last )
{
    Iterator min = First;
    for( Iterator i = First + 1; i < Last; ++i )
        if ( *i < *min )
            min = i;

    std::iter_swap( First, min );
    while( ++First < Last )
        for( Iterator j = First; *j < *(j - 1); --j )
            std::iter_swap( (j - 1), j );
}
```

It's the Insertion Sort and it sorts them from smallest to largest, however I have 2 issues:

1. Reversing any comparison sign doesn't change the sort order to descending.
2. When implementing it with my own container, it never sorts the last element. Maybe I didn't get how Begin and End should work for a container? This is how I make them:

If I have a dynamic array container that has an unsigned int size and a T* data, Begin returns an iterator that has a pointer to data[0] and End returns an iterator with a pointer to data[size - 1]. If I make end to instead return data[size], it works fine, however if the size is equal to the allocated capacity, that would overflow the buffer. So the presented insertion sort algorithm is incorrect then? I got it from this site:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Sorting/Insertion_sort#C.2FC.2B.2B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About question 1: I think it should work if you reverse all comparison signs that involve dereferenced iterators, i.e., replace

```
if ( *i < *min )
```

by

```
if ( *i > *min )
```

(one might also replace the name 'min' by 'max' then to avoid confusion), and

```
for( Iterator j = First; *j < *(j - 1); --j )
```

by

```
for( Iterator j = First; *j > *(j - 1); --j )
```

These are the comparisons that compare the actual data.

About question 2: usually, an 'end' iterator refers to the position *behind* the last actual item that you want to sort. Standard algorithms (such as yours) will never dereference this iterator, so no overflow will occur.

Answer (score 1):

The iterators pointing to an end() are one past the last element, so that you'd usually loop through them like:

```
for(Iterator it = begin(); it != end(); ++it) ...
```

Your iterator implementation thus stops one before that last and is the culprit.

It might be a good idea not to test everything at once, i.e. a custom algorithm with custom iterators. You can use a stl container to test the algorithm and an stl algorithm to test your container.

Comment: I see, I thought end() was just the last element, so I guess using end() to set an element results in undefined behavior